# Accessing static fields of a class from a non-Classname symbol

Tags: java, interop, clojure

Here's an extract from a REPL session that hopefully explains what I want to achieve:

```
user> (Integer/parseInt "1")
1
user> (def y Integer)
#'user/y
user> (y/parseInt "1")
No such namespace: y
  [Thrown class java.lang.Exception]
```

How can I access static method/fields of a Java class using a non-Classname, user defined symbol?

**UPDATE**

The following works as expected:

```
user> (eval (list (symbol (.getName y) "parseInt") "1"))
1
```

Is there a better/more idiomatic way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you explain why you would like to do this?

Comment: I have to cope with a poorly designed Java API, where a base Interface with no methods is extended by several other interfaces, providing one single method each. These methods are meant to be registered as callbacks by concrete implementations, which is done via reflection (e.g. `Registry.registerCallback(ImplementedInterface/CONDITION, concreteInstance, "callbackMethodName")`). I want to hide all the yak shaving code behind a more gentle Clojure API, thus I need to dynamically bind to an Interface and use reflection to perform the callback registration.

Comment: The eval approach has one sneaky drawback: eval cannot use variables in the local scope; it is as if it was executed at the top level. Therefore, (let [x 1] (eval '(inc x))) results in a "Unable to resolve symbol: x" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot determine the class (possibly programmatically in a macro) during compile time, you need to resort to use reflection. This would do the same thing as eval does when it tries to compile the code. See `clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeStaticMethod`: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L198

```
(import 'clojure.lang.Reflector)
;; Here, you can pass *any string you have at runtime*
(Reflector/invokeStaticMethod Integer "parseInt" (into-array ["1"]))
```

This can be used in arbitrary ways at runtime, since it's not a macro or a special form. For example, the name of the method could be given by the user via a GUI or though a socket at runtime.

If you have the name of the class at compile time, you can use a macro as Nicolas suggested. However, it's unnecessary to construct the code to look like `(Integer/parseInt "1")`, since it's just syntactic sugar for the more basic (and macro friendly) `.` special form: `(. Integer parseInt "1")`.

```
;; Here, the method name needs to be a *string literal*
(defmacro static-call
  "Takes a Class object, a string naming a static method of it
  and invokes the static method with the name on the class with
  args as the arguments."
  [class method & args]
  `(. ~class ~(symbol method) ~@args))
```

However, the only "real work" this macro performs is to convert the string into a symbol. You would probably just use the `.` special form in an outer macro (the one that acquires the names of the methods somehow, e.g. by getting those passed as arguments, or by reading them from a var or from a configuration file).

```
;; Use ordinary Clojure functions to construct this
(def the-static-methods {:foo ["Integer" "parseInt"], :bar ["Long" "parseLong"]})

;; Macros have access to all previously defined values
(defmacro generate-defns []
  (cons `do (for [[name-keyword [class-string method-string]] the-static-methods]
              `(defn ~(symbol (name name-keyword)) [x#]
                 (. ~(symbol class-string) ~(symbol method-string) x#)))))

(generate-defns)
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory the following approach could work:

You can write a macro def-alias that allows you to do (def-alias y Integer). This macro should:

- define a namespace 'y' (create-ns ...)
- find all methods for Integer (or any other class), using (.getMethods ...)
- dynamically create thin wrappers for all those methods in namespace 'y'

It's kinda ugly since this approach will also create wrappers for methods you don't need.

No guarantees ;)

Comment: thanks for the proposed approach. However, I updated the original question with another, more concise way to do the job. It's also kinda ugly, do you think it can be improved in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any better way than the `eval` call you provided. You could always wrap it up in a nice macro:

```
(defmacro static-call [var method & args]
  `(-> (.getName ~var)
       (symbol ~(str method))
       (list ~@args)
       eval))
```

**Update**: As suggested by raek here's a version using the `Reflector` class:

```
(defmacro static-call [var method & args]
  `(clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeStaticMethod
    (.getName ~var)
    ~(str method)
    (to-array ~(vec args))))
```

Note that I've written a macro in both cases only for the convenience of saving some characters. For better performance you should use `invokeStaticMethod` directly.

Comment: eval uses Clojure's Reflector class when it generates bytecode for the static call. You don't have to do this with eval since this class also offers methods for reflective calls: (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeStaticMethod ...)